# Как на рег ру разместить несколько фласк приложений на одном сайте?

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Есть 2 бека на фласке, их надо положить на рег ру, чтобы можно было делать потом запросы к ним с веб сайтов. Окружение фласка установил как у них в документации указано, там же написано, что питоновские файлы надо класть в корневой каталог сайта, все бы хоорошо, но у меня 2 таких приложения, как мне их правильно расположить на сайте, чтобы одно другое не перекрывало?

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что вы хостинг арендовали, а не VPS?

Answer (score 1):

По каждой составляющей можно нагуглить множество статей с примерами, здесь я опишу высокоуровневую картинку для цельного понимания происходящего:

### 1. Настройка кода

Настраиваете окружение для бэкэнда отдельных сайтов. Не важно, Python + Flask/Django или Node.js или что ещё, не особо важно, где оно в системе хранится (часто используется путь вида `/var/www/my-website`).

По-хорошему, для Питона можно использовать изолированные окружения через venv ([virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)), или вообще Docker для всего, но если число сайтов редко меняется или опыта/компетенций мало, то можно обойтись и общим системным окружением.

Желательно настроить проброс прослушиваемого порта из консольного аргумента, пригодится в дальнейшем. В Джанго это имеется по умолчанию, во Фласке можно [легко сделать самостоятельно](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm).

### 2. Запуск кода

Автоматизировать запуск серверных приложений через **systemctl** или **Docker-Compose**, что позволит автоматически их перезапускать в случае падения из-за ошибок, или вручную для выкатки новых версий. Приложениям в конфигах проставляем порты, удобно использовать единообразные вроде 80xx.

### 3. Роутинг

Установить и настроить **NginX** для перенаправления запросов по разным доменам к портам. Чтобы условный `my-site-1.ru:80/443` отправлялся на порт 8001 одного приложения, а `my-site-2.ru:80/443` на порт 8002 другого, и т.п. Можно и даже удобно использовать разные конфиги, что позволит проще управлять сайтами, в каждом независимо прописывать отдельные правила, чаще всего для обработки статического контента сайта (JS, CSS, медиа).

[В документации Фласка есть базовый пример настройки NginX](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/deploying/nginx/#configuration).